# How to show a Entity value of type array on list action in Sonata Admin Bundle?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

How Can I display array value on entitty in sonata admin bundle list action?
I've tried to do something like this:

```
            ->add('daysOfWeek', null, array('type' => 'array'))
```

in configureListFields method but then I get error:
"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a template for special fields, I don't think there is a such thing as "default" way of displaying array fields.

The anwser was to do it like so:

```
->add('daysOfWeek', 'array', array('template' => 'WshBackendBundle:EventAdmin:list_days_of_week.html.twig'))
```

Comment: `Could not load type "array"` Array type does not exist in Sonata, i'm i wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The template method is working well but for simple entity you can use the 'collection' type

I have a Post entity with many tags.
So the $tags variable in the Post entity is collection of Tag.

Now in your PostAdmin:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('name')
            ...
            ->add('tags', ' collection')
            ...
}
```

Then you need a toString method in your Tag entity.

```
function __toString() {
    return $this->getName();
}
```